# How to populate @Html.Textboxfor when we select a value from @Html.DropdownListfor

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I populate data into @Html.Textboxfor when we select value in @Html.DropdownListfor in ASP.NET MVC5 application. Which is the better way to populate the data in text box either by using scripting or is there any other way to do if so give me an example if possible.

Comment: @user3608792 You want him to hit the server every time someone changes the dropdown list value?

Comment: I have the get the values into the text box through DB when we select value in dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Use JavaScript. You should make a script where all your ajax calls come from a single point of entry. It's easier to reuse, maintain and easier to debug. Keep in mind this code is just an outline, your going to have to clean it up. Don't hit the server as suggested and update your view model every time a dropdown list value changes. That is ridiculous. I'll give you my full approach to this situation. Just pull in the view model from an `XMLHttpRequest` how ever you like and filter the current data you have every time the dropdown list changes.

step 1: Make a request to your controller for the view model

```
//quick example
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'Controller/Methodname');
xhr.send(null);
```

step2: Get the ViewModel and store it in an object or variable or w/e you want

```
    //handle the call
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
      var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
      if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === OK) 
          ...xhr.responseText // 'This is the returned text. so store it somewhere'
        } else {
          console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
        }
      }
    };
```

step 3: Add an onChange event for the dropdown list.

```
    onDropdownChange() {
       // based on what is selected, filter you data and populate the textbox
       document.getElementById("YourTextboxID").value = your value;      
    }
```

Comment: Can I write the javascript(not as above example) and execute it in MVC5. iF possible suggest me solution

Comment: @addadaSatish what do you mean execute it in MVC5? MVC is a design pattern. Please explain what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry I think I deleted this by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like This.

```
function ondropdownchange(){
    $.get("yourmethodurl", function(data, status){
         $('#yourtextbox').val(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: You didn't answer his question at all ` Which is the better way to populate the data in text box either by using scripting or is there any other way to do if so give me an example if possible.`